# Why exc_traceback returns None

Tags: python, exception, sys, traceback

[sys.exc_info()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html?highlight=sys#sys.exc_info) returns a tuple (type , value, traceback).
so `sys.exc_info()[2]` is our traceback object.

Why it does not catch exceptions traceback with this code:

```
import sys

try:
    1/0
except ZeroDivisionError:
    print sys.exc_info()[2].tb_frame.f_back
```

tb_frame and f_back usage has been explained here:
[Frame Objects](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#frame-objects)

Comment: It does have a traceback, otherwise you'd get an `AttributeError`, but the traceback's frame doesn't have a `f_back`. That seems perfectly sensible to me. If you're running this directly, *what outer frame were you expecting?*

Comment: in line 269 traceback.py module in standard library the same: tb_frame.f_back was used.

Comment: That doesn't really answer my question. *Why did you think there would be an outer frame*, in this case?

Comment: @Heartagramir That's because that code is inside the `print_stack` function, and we need to go one frame up, because we are not really interested in the `print_stack` function's own frame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You see `None` because *there is no outer frame*. You're executing this directly, so the current frame is the last frame. To demonstrate this, I created a `demo.py`:

```
import sys

try:
    1/0
except ZeroDivisionError:
    print sys.exc_info()[2].tb_frame.f_back
```

which should look familiar, and a trivial `caller.py`:

```
import demo
```

Now see the difference:

```bash
$ python demo.py
None

$ python caller.py
<frame object at 0x10bc34c20>
```

In the second case, where there is an outer frame (i.e. `caller.py`), you don't see `None`.

Comment: well your comment was more like solution... my question was the result of my lack of knowledge of frames. now I get to know frame more clearly... I suggest editing your solution and add some information about frame and f_back usage in other frames.

Comment: @Heartagramir what exactly does *"add some information about frame and f_back usage in other frames"* mean? Do you have a specific question I could answer? What is unclear?

Comment: Everything is clear for me it was just a suggestion thanks again.

Comment: @Heartagramir no problem; if you have a specific suggestion let me know, but I'm not just going to keep writing in the hope that something helps!